# UnsatisfiedDependency exception on using DefaultMapperFactory orika

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, orika

I am trying to run a springboot microservice which is already implemented, locally. I am not getting any help from the people who has a working environment. The application uses ma.glasnost.orika,MapperFacade, MapperFactory and DefaultMapperFactory. Bean Instantiation is failing with factory method. Can someone please help me with the issue.
I see bootstrap.yml file which has server and application name and also AppConfig.java where we are creating beans to getUsername, and value property define on field. Where should these be added in local to test it locally.
I am expecting a successful execution of spring boot application

```
class AppConfig{
     @Value("${service.usename}"
     private String userName;
     @Bean
       public String appUserName(){
         return userName;}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.